# Inheritance and Object creation, Theoretically and in Real

Tags: java, inheritance, memory-management

Lets say I have a class `A.java`,

[image]

When I will execute a constructor method of A, it will create a memory space for `xyz` Object.

```
A xyz = new A();
```

The reference to memory may be something like,

```
[xyz] ---> '0x34524'
```

Thats basics of OOP. Simple enough!

#### Now,

What happens if a class is inheriting from different parent classes? How many object space will be created in memory?

Lets say we have,

[image]

and then we create an object of class `D.java`,

```
D omg = new D();
```

Here as we know that D's object will call construct of C.java and so on until A.java. Does this mean that in memory we are having 4 different memory reference, because we are instantiating all of the four objects (one directly and another 3 indirectly)?

```
[omg] ---> '0x34525'
[C]   ---> '0x34526'
[B]   ---> '0x34527'
[A]   ---> '0x34528'
```

---

**Note :**

1. This isn't homework question, this is just a curiosity question.
2. I am aware of the fact that if we have a instance variable inside an A.java then we will not create only object A but we will be creating other internal object whenever we hit `new` keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672109/memory-allocation-for-a-class-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a tid bit... calling the constructor of an object does not allocate it. In bytecode, the initialization `new Object()` is expressed as something to the effect of...

```
new java/lang/Object
invokespecial java/lang/Object <init>()V
```

The [`new`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new) instruction takes care of allocating the space and acquiring a reference to the yet *uninitialized* object, while the [`invokespecial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial) handles calling the constructor itself (which is internally compiled to a [`void` method named `<init>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9), hence the [descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3) `<init>()V`).

Moving on, internals of object allocation and [representation on the heap are entirely JVM specific](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.7). However, as far as I know, there is only **one** allocated object per allocated object, no matter its  number of super classes. The object itself in memory has space for the instance fields of both its own class and its super classes. It must also have space for a [*virtual method table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), in order to do virtual dispatch when performing virtual method calls (e.g. via [`invokevirtual`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.4.5.invokevirtual)) for the object.

Internally, the Oracle HotSpot JVM manages things called *oops*, or ordinary object pointers. You can read more about the HotSpot memory layout [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops). Feel free to [browse the HotSpot source repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/).

Comment: An object's fields are resolved statically, so you can know at compile time exactly how big the full object would be, as well as the offsets for each of its fields. Moreover, each override of a given method always uses the same field offset, since fields are statically resolved. So I don't know of any reason why the JVM would instants ate four objects instead of one.

Comment: The compiler does not resolve where fields are in memory, the JVM does... the Java allocates one object in memory and executes the code from the super class constructors from the immediate super class up to `Object` (inside the constructor, it is possible other objects are constructed too e.g. for field initialization).

Answer (score 1):

JVM allocates memory for only one object (here D)

1. memory allocation and initialization happens  bottom(here D) to top(Object)
2. initialization/calling constructors happens Top(Object) to Bottom(here D)

reference :

http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not read this anywhere but its my experience.
When you call `new D()`, the constructor chain begins, it first creates an `java.lang.Object` and then `extends` it to an `A`, I mean after creating the `Object` (which is root of all objects), A is initialized on it, by adding memory for A's members, including fields and methods (which are a pointer to some code!). And then it `extends` to B and so on.

In the process of extension if a method is overriden, the method pointer in the object will point to new code.

It will be only one reference to D.