# how parent and child classes mix when creating a child class object

Tags: java, inheritance

When we instantiate a Child class object, the parent class's constructor is also called. So is it a creation of an object of the parent class?

Comment: A constructor doesn't instantiate a class, it initializes an instance. When the super constructor is invoked, it is invoked to initialize the parent aspect of the instance.

Comment: Nope.  There is only one object, but both constructors are being called on it.

Comment: then who is the responsible for instantiate a class ?

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877615/how-many-objects-are-created-due-to-inheritance-in-java

Answer (score 0):

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877615/how-many-objects-are-created-due-to-inheritance-in-java) when you instantiate child class using new operator only child class object will create. you can think as parent constructor code is in child constructor code because of inheritance

Comment: `only child class object will create` doesn't feel complete to me. Especially since `child instanceof parent` will return true.