# How many objects are created in inheritance?

Tags: java

If only one then how Parent class constructor gets executed when sub class object is create

```html
class Parent
{
 Parent()
 {
  System.out.println("Parent class construcor");
 }
}
class Child extends Parent 
{
 Child()
 {
  System.out.println("Child class construcor");
 }
 
}
 class Test
 {
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
   Child obj = new Child();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Physically you could see only class Child obj, but it has access to all the non-private members.  In terms of memory, it occupies both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914609/1002790 Already answered.