# private variable inheritance in java

Tags: java

Look at the code below:

```
class Rodent {
    private String hello = "hello" ;

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println(hello);
    }
}

public class Mouse extends Rodent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
        mouse.printHello();

    }
}
```

If we see , the method printHello() is inherited. This method is inside using a private variable. But this private variable is not inherited. Then how does this code works ?

Is it something similar like closure in JavaScript ?

If method `printHello()` is inherited and it needs some private variable , then this also has to be made available in `Mouse` as now I am calling `printHello()` in `Mouse` ?

**Edit** : For those who say that parent class method will be called , I have found that there is only object created and not separate objects one for sub class and one for parent class.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877615/how-many-objects-are-created-due-to-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)

Comment: Who says private variables aren't inherited? Of course it is inherited. Only the access is restricted via the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:

> [Do subclasses inherit private fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields)

The instance of subclass contains its superclass private fields. So, in a sense `private String hello` is inherited.

But as a private field it is not accessible outside of `Rodent`. But it's also not accessed outside of `Rodent` in your code.

Comment: Just wondering if it is right to say it is *inherited* (From the update to DigitalRoss's answer on that question)

Comment: @user7 , no we cannot say it is inherited however it is `present` in the object so created.

Comment: @user7 My wording is "in a sense". In a sense that this private field of the superclass is actually contained in an object instance of subclass. Strictly speaking - you're probably correct.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin What is the difference between an inherited method and an inherited field then?

Comment: @lexicore See every thing is `present` in the object only , in the end , but among what is `present` , we say `inherited` only for as JLS dictates :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2 Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Strictly speaking, you are right, yes. Therefore the *in a sense* wording which is my only excuse here.

Answer (score 1):

`mouse.printHello()`

Calls the `printHello` method in class `Rodent` and not `Mouse` and hence it has access to the private variable `hello`. As you have said, it is inherited.

Think of it like this: (though the terms are not correct)

Class `Rodent` has the method `printHello` and private variable `hello`. But the method being public, it is *visible* from `Mouse` (but still it is **in** the Rodent class).

However, if you add a method to `Mouse` and try to access the variable `hello`, it will result in a compilation error.